# Why does some information in an Autocomplete response differ from what is returned in a subsequent Details response?

Tags: google-places-api

When I perform a Google Places Autocomplete request for "98 Spru" I get a Place prediction with one id (013ae3e513081ff1bc9e3dc202df54ba9d147285) and one set of types ("route" and "geocode") but when I fetch for the details of that Place it has a different id (5e66bbb5a5a7eaedd07fabc199e87570bcc0eae6) and a different set of types ("street_address")? The rest of the information is correct. Snippets of requests / responses below.

Is this expected and if so why?

On the client side I'm trying to filter out Autocomplete predictions that are not of some specific type (e.g. "street_address"). This doesn't work since the "types" field in the Autocomplete response doesn't consistently match the "true" types value as returned in the Details response.

Thanks!

Autocomplete Request / Response for "98 Spru"
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=98%20Spru&sensor=true&key=MYKEY&location=42.350000,-71.160000&radius=100.000000&types=geocode

```
  {
     "description" : "98 Spruce Street, Watertown, MA, United States",
     "id" : "013ae3e513081ff1bc9e3dc202df54ba9d147285",
     "matched_substrings" : [
        {
           "length" : 7,
           "offset" : 0
        }
     ],
     "reference" : "CmRcAAAArJjcgqYuczq9wKmQG0lwv6j_uCBYCrWzS_U76FvnV3fCnWq0_pPf-nu6M9eTYQEpYt4XahA3Vg0GSzMcR23k3Mkxp9sv73ObGmeHDcanEnZ0dWpl69t7eSwmzLbrREQfEhA0CrWTEXtfQhcnfNWnqTukGhQFWBj_lPkoAwG-ZvUIv0GZhgAscQ",
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "98 Spruce Street"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 18,
           "value" : "Watertown"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 29,
           "value" : "MA"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 33,
           "value" : "United States"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "route", "geocode" ]
  },
```

Details Request / Response from above prediction:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MYKEY&sensor=true&reference=CmRcAAAAzcupmv2dCaIWTnySJhA8y4BIc5_VSj1AUXCBFHEVnuo3NGjuqAVrLGSVZ_NODQstUs1ZclGASEzBYTF0B1nFSAcjgrc7Jn9NhJC2GZ2RtQQ3REFV7pvBzTPoGOHew289EhAD7dQFOe2EvBjpQ46IKODbGhTH0scvHs54U3refjf1-Tn6-04XvQ

```
{
   "debug_info" : [],
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "98",
            "short_name" : "98",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Spruce St",
            "short_name" : "Spruce St",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Watertown",
            "short_name" : "Watertown",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Middlesex",
            "short_name" : "Middlesex",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Massachusetts",
            "short_name" : "MA",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United States",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "02472",
            "short_name" : "02472",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003e98 Spruce St\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eWatertown\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eMA\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e02472\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eUSA\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "98 Spruce St, Watertown, MA 02472, USA",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 42.3667790,
            "lng" : -71.1698590
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
      "id" : "5e66bbb5a5a7eaedd07fabc199e87570bcc0eae6",
      "name" : "98 Spruce St",
      "reference" : "CpQBhgAAABX6gm9Qh9r9QxMuEWIrwFGcsz2QnUG0MAoEkD33kwrxfcEakZh-d01oWlAFnIieF8MvVcflI7xJ91Qq2ahnw9oDjcUPUnhlRcOUjLF0lTXOWf3Fp3dbCqLo3MQxCDGT3UJj5fR4ZrPagqBYXtQcPl1TB6sgPHZv8x-2jdJzbh-yZ6yb9VhfG-KDD76-RdotkRIQ7Oz0mKuwaclr0xiIf4oHehoUM2l9nZsi5pU2RPyB7YA2lmJ7vI0",
      "types" : [ "street_address" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=98+Spruce+St&ftid=0x89e3781f4bba528d:0xa7ec6e9a6bde2e4f",
      "vicinity" : "Watertown"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Any update? I've noticed this issue too where the ID is different for autocomplete and the place details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the googleId thats returned by the autocomplete API. You need to use the reference, make an API call to Place Details API, then use that ID. I believe sometimes Google will consolidate their places database such that the reference will 'redirect' to a new place.